# mysql: copying to tmp table - only for innodb tables

Tags: mysql, select, innodb, temp-tables

I have a simple `JOIN` like this:

```
select a.id 
from tablex a, tabley b 
where a.id_fk=b.id 
order by a.id 
limit 5;
```

If tables are MyISAM everything is ok. The result of "explain" is `"Using index"`.
If the same tables with the same data are InnoDB, the result of "explain" is `"Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"`.

What is wrong with InnoDB configuration? What variable should I modify to use indexes?

This is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2x` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_licitatie_idx` (`id_fk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=116902 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `table2y` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=49116 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `tablex` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_licitatie_idx` (`id_fk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116902 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `tabley` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49116 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: Can you validate that the table structures, indexes, data contents, and hardware are the same for both databases?  What are the index definitions?  I would expect the database engine to use an index for the `join` and filesort for the `order by`, without very careful engineering.

Comment: I have 2 simple INNODB tables. I converted them to MyISAM and renamed them. More details in the image: http://www.costinel.com/sql.png